# Hidden Some Setting on Post or Page

Tags: plugins, posts, pages

[image]

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, but i want to remove this (in the red mark) from non-admin, what plugins to disable this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove custom metaboxes from custom post type](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118888/remove-custom-metaboxes-from-custom-post-type) or [How do I remove all the metaboxes for a custom post type?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176832/how-do-i-remove-all-the-metaboxes-for-a-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0):

Please User Role Permission  Plugin For user wise Permission

[Link here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Comment: But, how to remove or hidden them?